# The bigger the payroll the harder it is to replenish , let alone expand

Tags: verbs

1. The  "let" is verb or past participle ?
2. Does the sentence have two verbs ?

Answer (score 1):

"Let alone" is a phrase used to say that something is even more difficult to do than another thing. ([dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/let-alone)) "Let" is a verb in imperative form, but the meaning is from the idiom. Don't try to understand it word-by-word.

It means that it is very difficult to replenish a payroll, and it is even harder to expand a payroll.

I count four verbs: "is", "replenish", "let" and "expand".  The main verb is "is"

Comment: thank you very much